# RecyclerView programmatically click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to programmatically click on an item of a recyclerView. I'm using:

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index).itemView.performClick();
```

This perfectly works when the index is of a visible item. If the item is not visible (at  the last position of the recyclerview, for istance), an Exception is thrown.

What can I do?

Comment: You should see this answer [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/3005903)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `onClick` directly, assuming that view manages its own click listener.

```
View view = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index).itemView;
view.onClick(view);
```

If the click listener is located somewhere else, you just need to get a reference to the object with the `onClick` method and call it with the correct view as a parameter.

Comment: i have tried your solution but i m getting null pointer exception when the item is not visible

Answer (score 10):

I just had a similar question with yours.And I had solve it! Here is what I did.

```
xxx.mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                xx.mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
            }
        },300);


        xxx.mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                xxx.mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.performClick();
                }
            },400);
        }
```

You can scroll to the specific item, then perform click.
Because the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)) say

> If the item at the given position is not laid out, it will not create a new one.

But I know the adapter has the data, so scroll to it first, and `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`will not be null.

One more thing, I do not know how you use the RecyclerView. In my application, I use it in a fragment, and I don not know why we should delay it scroll and perform click. (Maybe it is because of the life circle?).But this really works.

Answer (score 2):

try this for kotlin and viewBinding

```
 viewBinding.catList.post {
            val view = viewBinding.catList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)?.itemView?.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.catButton)
            view?.callOnClick()
        }
```